# Sending tagged traffic to lxc container while sending untagged traffic to other containers

Tags: linux-networking, vlan, bridge, lxc

I have a situation where I already have several bridges on my lxc host to send vlan-specific traffic to my various containers.  I have one container that lives on several of the networks, and was curious if it's possible to send traffic to this one container still tagged, so I don't have to change its lxc config when I add a new network.

My current config looks something like this:

```
auto br10
iface br10 inet manual
  bridge_ports eth0.10
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_fd 0

auto br20
iface br20 inet manual
  bridge_ports eth0.20
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_fd 0
```

I'd like to add something like this

```
auto br-tagged
iface br-tagged inet manual
  bridge_ports eth0.10 eth0.20 eth0.30
```

but I can't do that, because the devices are already bound to the other bridges

Comment: It's not that difficult to setup an *unique* bridge with vlan filtering enabled to do this . What is then more difficult is the configuration for the ifupdown and the LXC parts rather than manual commands.